# Grails jquery post only working with an alert present?

Tags: jquery, grails, post, alert

So, I've got a link on a page which calls a little jQuery function, which in turn posts to a controller, the controller just runs some SQL before refreshing the page.

All this works nicely, while debugging it with lots of alerts etc to make sure things are doing what I want.  BUT, once I remove all the alerts it stops working?!  Any ideas?  You can see the commented out alert in the function below, commented out nothing happens, no SQL update, nothing.  If I add that alert back in it then works fine?!

Has anyone ever come across this or found a way around it?  Is there a way/obvious reason why this is happening?  Cheers!

jQuery function

```
function reQueueTest(url, id){
    $.post(url, { id:id },function(data){   
    });
    //alert("work!")
    location.reload(true);
}
```

Controller

```
def reQueueTest(int id){
    def sql = new Sql(dataSource)

    def rowID = id
    sql.executeUpdate "update test_exec_queue set [State]='READY' where test_exec_queue_id=$rowID"
    sql.close()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

Ok, so try to reload in the done method:

```
function reQueueTest(url, id){
    $.post(url, { id:id },function(data){   
        }).done(function() { location.reload(true); })
          .fail(function() { alert("error"); })
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, I tried that and it didn't seem to work either, didnt post/run the SQL or refresh the page! :S

Comment: hmmm, interestingly when I try this I get the error message pop up!  But if I then replace the error alert with a second reload it then reloads fine!  So whatever is causing it to fail its still working so looks like the issue lies more in the controller somewhere somehow, but this works for now so I'm happy, cheers! :)